# I'm trying to create new objects, and add them to a list of objects, However I am running to some issues, here

Tags: c#, object, text-files

What I've attempted: I printed out each element in the `BookFields` array, to make sure id is 1, title is "Head First Python, etc. and each element seems to have the correct index from the line split. I reviewed the code, and I'm not catching anything that can be causing this error, due to the elements displaying like they should. Where have I gone wrong?

I still keep getting this error message, despite parsing id to an int:

[image: Error Message screenshot]

[book.txt file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzsL4.png)

[Printed Elements in BookFields, but getting an Out of Bounds Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moemD.png)

[Code screenshot of elements printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHBu4.png)

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    var BookCsvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"/Users/jasonampah/Desktop/Book.txt").ToList();

    var AllBooks = new List<Book>() { };

    foreach (string line in BookCsvData)
    {
        string[] Bookfields = line.Split(',');

        Book Newbook = new Book();
        Newbook.id = int.Parse(Bookfields[0]);
        Newbook.Title = Bookfields[1];
        Newbook.Synopsis = Bookfields[2];
        Newbook.Author = Bookfields[3];
        Newbook.YearPublished = Bookfields[4];
        Newbook.ISBN = long.Parse(Bookfields[5]);

        AllBooks.Add(Newbook);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your file have two empty lines after the last valid line?

Comment: There is really no need to perform the `ToList()` method on `ReadAllLines` since the result of `ReadAllLines` is a `string[]` object on which you can use `Foreach` loop.

Comment: Does Bookfields has 5 items? Did you check `Bookfields.Length`?

Comment: Did you debug your code and check what exact values you are getting in `Bookfields` array? Specially `Bookfields[5]`?

Comment: A ISBN code is not a `long`, of course, it's a string (because it is. You can see your own text file: it begins with a `0`). You probably have an empty line which, when read, will cause the exception. So, before acting on it, do check `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim())) continue;`. You should also check `Bookfields.Length` after you have split the input string.

Answer (score 0):

What type is the Books' ISBN field? I think that's where the problem lies.

Also, you don't have to implement CSV reading yourself, there some cool libraries out there that can do it for you. I'd recommend CSVHelper but there are others, have a look.

Comment: will look into CSVhelper, thanks, and ISBN field is a long,

Comment: The error message states "at System.Number.ParseInt32.." which means the error is occurring here: "int.Parse(Bookfields[0]);" .. that doesn't mean it couldn't eventually happen where  "ISBN" is being parsed, just not yet. That is why the OP should use `TryParse()` instead. However, there appears to be a lot of information missing from the OP's question statement.